# How to set up a button to play audio every time it's clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a hook that plays a provided audio file the first time it's clicked, and then every other time (false, true, false). I'd like it to play every time it's clicked regardless if it's the 1st time or 15th time. I've been trying different approaches, but so far I'm struggling to think of a clean solution to get this to work.

Any ideas how I can set the audio to start over each time it's clicked?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const useAudio = (url) => {
  const [audio, setAudio] = useState(new Audio(url));
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setPlaying(!playing);
  };

  // ! file might not be cleaning up
  useEffect(() => {
    setAudio(new Audio(url));
    setPlaying(false);
  }, [url]);

  useEffect(() => {
    playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
  }, [playing]);

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, [url]);

  return [playing, toggle];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the `currentTime` property of the audio object to `0`. So, it will seek back to the 0th second. Then try again.

Syntax:

```
audio.currentTime = 0
```

In your code, you can try:

```
useEffect(() => {
    audio.currentTime = 0
    playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
  }, [playing]);
```